# invalid application error in j2me app

Tags: java, java-me

i have made a j2me in eclipse juno and   WTK 2.5.2. complied successfully, when i run it in real device 
nokia give error invalid application. use MIDP 2.0 and cldc 1.1 .

manifest file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0

MIDlet-Version: 1.0.0

MIDlet-1: Main,

MicroEdition-Configuration: CLDC-1.1

MIDlet-Data-Size: 0

MIDlet-Icon: logo.png, recharge.jpg

MIDlet-Name: Main

MicroEdition-Profile: MIDP-2.0

MIDlet-Permissions: javax.microedition.io.connector.http, javax.microedition.io.Connector.https
```

Comment: i m testing in nokia c1

Comment: Try MIDP 2.1 for nokia c1

Comment: tested in 2.1 also but not working

Comment: IS sun WTK 2.5.2 support nokia series phones

Comment: Should be. Why do you have MIDlet-Data-Size: 0 ?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your manifest, it looks like you're missing some attributes:

`MIDlet-1` is missing icon and class name. It should state something like `MIDlet-1: Main,myicon.png,com.mystuff.mymidlet`

`MIDlet-Jar-Size` is missing, probably because you haven't selected the main MIDlet in your project properties.

`MIDlet-Jar-URL` is missing, again probably because you haven't selected the main MIDlet in your project properties.

So check your project properties.

---

`Invalid Application Error` also often shows up when there are attributes in the JAD/manifest file that isn't supported by the device.
For Nokia, this is true even when we're talking about Nokia's own invented attributes.
You could use Nokia specific JAD attributes - and you'd get an `Invalid Application Error` on a lot of Nokia devices because they don't support this particular attribute.

To test this, try removing all special attributes and only have the standard ones.

(But in your case, it looks like you just haven't selected the main MIDlet in your project properties).